# Xamarin.iOS Pdf search

Tags: objective-c, pdf, xamarin.ios

We develop with Xamarin.iOS and are trying to search/highlight in a PDF.
There is an iOS class for searching, CGPDFScanner, but unfortunately no bindings are offered by Xamarin.

Is there a solution or we should forget about it?

We believe that there is a way to make bindings for existing iOS classes.
Or we could probably use an existing project, like PDFKitten, and make Xamarin bindings.
Any hints?

Comment: I recommend PSPDFKit (http://pspdfkit.com). There are Xamarin bindings available (https://github.com/PSPDFKit/Xamarin-v3). It is an awesome library - and very expensive. I used it in a previous project and worked on the bindings.

Comment: Hi, yes we found this lib but having to pay so much "just" for searching in a PDF seems a lot to us... We also tryied PDFKitten but it doesn't work very well with French/German languages

Comment: I've seen in Xamarin Component Store some native Xamarin.iOS libraries for working with PDF files. They might help you with the task.

Comment: Try this one: https://components.xamarin.com/view/XFINIUM.PDF - all managed code.

Comment: if you find a native API that does not have bindings, you should file a bug with Xamarin

Comment: I did now: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17393

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin offers way for creating binding library. If you have some working and tested solution available in Objective C, create Binding library in tamarin and use that. You can check detailed document of it from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/)

I have created  binding library for one of my project where i had to integrate [third party sdk](http://wootric.com/) which was only in objective C. I followed step given [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/) and it worked.